# Where to securely store Google_Application_Credentials in Django project?

Tags: python, django, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have a Django project that uses the Google API. I created a docker-compose.yml which has my Django container and Nginx container. It builds successfully but when I run docker-compose up, I get following error:

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /file/path/credentials.json was not found.`

I have installed the Google SDK and ran 'gcloud auth application-default login' which creates the json file in my root directory. I then created an environment variable for it and configured my Django app.

settings.py:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
```

I can open the credentials json file in my finder so I know it's there.

The Google API is being used for secret manager to retrive secret keys:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import environ

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()


def get_secret(secret_id, version_id="latest"):
    project_id = env("GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID")
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"
    response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)
    return response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
```

Without running docker-compose up it works fine and I can retrieve keys but I want to test it out running my docker containers.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

I even tried downloading the service account key which places it in my downloads folder

When I move the file into the django project, it can ready it but from my understanding, you should't have the credentials file in the source code. So where should I store the credentials for this to work securely?

Comment: Where is running your Django application? On Google Cloud or elsewhere?

Comment: On my local machine in my home directory. My objective is to test out the project with docker locally before pushing to google cloud

Comment: So, you don't use a service account key file. I wrote an article about that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Comment: Ok, so when i run ADC=~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json \
docker run \
<YOUR PARAMS> \
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json \
-v ${ADC}:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro \
<IMAGE_URL> do i replace docker run with docker-compose up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps here you're missing to use a local service account in the container without actually storing it there or adding it to your git repo:

I'll speak in generalities and then you can add these to your `docker-compose.yml`:

#### Where Should The Google Services Look

The environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` tells the Google services where it should look for a service account *in the container*. So in your service, set an environment variable with an absolute path *in the container* where these Google services should look:

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/keys/application_default_credentials.json
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
```

#### Mapping From Your Local Machine

Because you don't want to store the service account in your repo, you need to set up a `volume` in your `docker-compose.yml` that maps the above `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the service account on your local machine. If you have your service account at `/jdez/Downloads/service-account.json`, you'll set up your volume like this:

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/keys/application_default_credentials.json
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    volumes:
      - /jdez/Downloads/service-account.json:/tmp/keys/application_default_credentials.json
```

Now when the Google services look for the file at `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, they'll read the one in your `Downloads` directory.

Because you're using a service account, you don't even need to run `gcloud` unless you need it for other things.

Comment: Once I push to Google Cloud, will this still be good? Or will I need to go back and configure it? I read somewhere that said not to use volume in production

Comment: If you push to Google Cloud (like Cloud Run), you'd have it build from the Dockerfile and Google will automatically inject the credentials based on the service account you configure in Cloud Build or Cloud Run. So yes - this allows you to develop locally with docker compose and then use the Dockerfile to build and run at Google Cloud without the service account even leaving your machine. Just be sure to give the Cloud Run (or whatever) service account the right permissions to talk to the services you're using.